# Is there a more optimal way to do dynamic filtering in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking to do filtering on a set of data using fields that change based on the category of items. This means there could be an infinite number of fields that I'd need to be able to run searches on.

Due to the indexing, if I chain where clauses, I'm likely to create a combination that requires, but does not have, an index.

My code is simple so far, if you picture the data set in Firestore looking like this:

```
item (document within items)
     name
     ...
     meta:
          year: 2019
          brand: Apple
          size: medium

category (document within categories)
     name
     ...
     availableFields:
          year
          brand
          size
```

and a client-side object looking like:

```
yearFilter {
    slug: 'year',
    operator: '==',
    value: '2019'
},
sizeFilter {
    slug: 'size',
    operator: '==',
    value: 'medium'
},
```

this is where I generate my query:

```
var catItemsQuery = db.collection(`items`)
for(var key in whereClauses){
    let clause = whereClauses[key]
    catItemsQuery = catItems.where(`meta.${clause.slug}`, clause.operator, clause.value)
}
```

It seems like a fairly straightforward set up, and should work if not for the indices required. I know the maximum number of composite indexes for a database is 200 so I need to re-architect, open to doing whatever necessary here! Thank you!

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/cjdbcu/whats_the_most_optimal_way_to_do_dynamic_filtering/

Comment: Thanks for linking to them, I'll do the same if find a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a bit more complex than I would have thought it needed to be, but seems to be working fine.

The solution that I'm going with is this (of course, always open to improvement):

Instead of different field names for each of the different categories that may exist, each category has a mapping of common field names to their true name.

For example this may be one category's mapping:

```
field: meta0
name: "Brand"
```

and another:

```
field: meta0
name: "Year"
```

This allows me to do a search for meta0..N without needing to worry about chaining different names.

For anybody interested in the reason this works: it makes the filters predictable, and with a limit on the number of meta fields, you can create the necessary composite indices.

The number of permutations for 5 filters will look something like:

- with 1 `where` clause: 5 (these don't matter, not composite)
- with 2 chained `where` clauses: 10
- with 3 chained `where` clauses: 10
- with 4 chained `where` clauses: 5
- with 5 chained `where` clauses: 1

total combos is 26. 26 out of the allowed 200 composite indices seems OK. It's really not great, but it's *a* solution as of now.